# Zxing License jai-imageio

Tags: licensing, zxing, jai

i have a question about the ZXing library license.
The biggest part is the part about the Apache 2.0 license, which is no problem.

I noticed there was a part added a few month ago under jai-imageio.
What exactly mean the 2 parts behind the hyphen?

Do i need to include these copyrights and license when i publish an application like with the apache license?
Or does my application also need to be published under the same license as mentioned?

The license can be found here:
https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/LICENSE

Forgive me for asking, i'm not a native english speaker, and its hard to understand the business language in these license.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

The LICENSE file (all-caps in the original file-name) contains two licenses.

The first one as you wrote yourself looks like the **Apache-2** license to you. I have not extensively verified it, but it looks to me as well like the Apache 2 license.

From a quick glimpse, the second license in that file is a BSD type of license, I first thought it's with 2 clauses, but it actually is a **BSD-3-Clause** one, the third clause is missing a dash in front, perhaps a mistake when copying it over.as

**Why are there two licenses?**

I don't know the software you linked, I can imagine that it consists of another software ("jai-imageio") which is licensed under such a lax BSD-type license.

These BSD-type licenses require that they are kept verbatim to not loose usage rights. That is normally the reason why devs do add more and more licenses to the LICENSE file so that in a central place all licenses used in the project are visible.

Compare for example with the [X-Server projects licenses documentation](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xorg-docs/License.html), the bigger a project grows, the more third-party code it contains and this requires some maintenance on the licenses as well, like collecting them in a license file or directory.